# What if Deoxys dies on your second try?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I read a question here that told me to beat the Elite Four again to find Deoxys on the Sky Tower, but I did that and I accedently killed it, any other chances?

Comment: You can challenge Elite Four again, it should re-spawn as long as you don't catch it.

Comment: Have you actually tried defeating the Elite Four *again* and it didn't spawn a third time, or why are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

Defeat Elite Four again and it will spawn again.

Answer (score 0):

Every legendary that you haven't caught (except Rayquaza who you have to capture in order to progress the story sequence) will still respawn after beating the Elite Four.